# Docusign call back from Docusign Connect not happening on change signer

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign connect so on any event on the envelope my public API gets the invoked. I am getting call backs from all the events except when the signer is changed. I expect that when the intended signer delegates the signature to some other user my public api is called through Docusign Connect.

Is there any setting on the Connect which I might be missing ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to upvote ALL useful answers (including answers to other people's questions). And approve/select the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new notification is sent, but I agree that the information is obscure.

The new notification includes a new RecipientStatus element (for the person delegated to) with Status `sent`

In addition, the recipient type for the original signer is changed from signer to `CarbonCopy` and the status goes to `Completed`

You can try this out and observe the notifications by using the [Web Hook recipe.](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status) You can try it live, free, on Heroku.

I agree that the notification should be more explicit about what happened and I'll file a DocuSign-internal enhancement request.

In the meantime, you can compare the number of recipients in the notification messages with the number that you had when you sent the envelope to see if something has changed. (Or compare with the first notification that you were sent when you sent the envelope.)

[I work for DocuSign]

**Added**

> We have already coded using the carbon copy tag for the signer who has delegated the signature to other signer. The problem is we do not receive the notification at the time of delegation.

Answer: I think what you're experiencing is the general issue that the notification system currently polls the platform. This means that, currently, specific notifications can be missed if a subsequent notification is observed. Notifications are not "generated," they're "observed" by the notification system.

When a signer re-assigns, a notification will be sent to your listener the next time the db is observed with the facts that a new signer has status `created` and the old signer is now a `cc`. That notification can take up to a minute or so to be observed and sent to your listener.

However, if there is yet another change during that time, eg, the assigned-to person receives or signs, then that first notification will be skipped since statuses of `delivered` and `signed` are higher than `created`

> We are using a demo account. Is this a problem with the demo accounts?

Answer: No. In general, the demo platform, demo.docusign.net is the exact same code as the production platforms. The main difference is that (approved and tested) updates are pushed to demo first, then production.

> Another observation is that when the delegated user signs the agreement we get the call back, but the user who is supposed to be marked as Carbon Copy (the user who delegates the signature) is marked as signer.

Answer: I don't know about this. Please raise this as a different question on StackOverflow. And include a test certificate of completion so this behavior can be checked.

Comment: We have already coded using the carbon copy tag for the signer who has delegated the signature to other signer. The problem is we do not receive the notification at the time of delegation. We are using a demo account. Is this a problem with the demo accounts?

Another observation is that when the delegated user signs the agreement we get the call back, but the user who is supposed to be marked as Carbon Copy (the user who delegates the signature) is marked as signer.

Comment: See my expanded answer