# Recipient type for the original signer is not changed from signer to CarbonCopy

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I have goan through the answer for below question

[Docusign call back from Docusign Connect not happening on change signer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936920/docusign-call-back-from-docusign-connect-not-happening-on-change-signer#_=)_

My question is - In the callback ( using legacy data format ) I dont see reciepient's type changed to "CarbonCopy" for original signer who has delegated to another signer rather I see the "delegated to" having "Signer" as type in the callback.

Is this something related to Connect configuration? I didn't found relevant setting actually.

This works for my demo account though, but not for customer's DocuSign account.
I have handled this "CarbonCopy" tag in the integration so this is needed information for me.

Is there any setting at account level that controls the recipient type for the original signer is changed from signer to CarbonCopy?

Edit-
In Below sample, mainsigner@yyy.com has delegated to delegatedto@yyy.com , So I would expect a new RecipientStatus node for mainsigner@yyy.com with Type as "CarbonCopy"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
            <RecipientStatus>
                <Type>CarbonCopy</Type>
                <Email>abc@xxx.com</Email>
                <UserName>ABC</UserName>
                <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                <Sent>2021-10-28T11:51:53.177</Sent>
                <DeclineReason/>
                <Status>Completed</Status>
                <RecipientIPAddress/>
                <CustomFields>
                    <CustomField>NonSignerCarbonCopy</CustomField>
                    <CustomField/>
                    <CustomField/>
                </CustomFields>
                <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
                <RecipientId>d4bee1ca-8af2-4d45-83b9-xxxxxxxxx</RecipientId>
            </RecipientStatus>
            <RecipientStatus>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                <Email>delegatedto@yyy.com</Email>
                <UserName>delegatedto</UserName>
                <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                <Sent>2021-11-04T07:44:41.59</Sent>
                <Delivered>2021-11-04T07:55:46.007</Delivered>
                <Signed>2021-11-04T07:56:03.007</Signed>
                <DeclineReason/>
                <Status>Completed</Status>
                <RecipientIPAddress>ipaddress</RecipientIPAddress>
                <CustomFields>
                    <CustomField>S||mainsigner@yyy.com</CustomField>
                    <CustomField/>
                    <CustomField/>
                </CustomFields>
                <TabStatuses>
                    <TabStatus>
                        <TabType>SignHere</TabType>
                        <Status>Signed</Status>
                        <XPosition>187</XPosition>
                        <YPosition>508</YPosition>
                        <TabLabel>Sign Here</TabLabel>
                        <TabName>SignHere</TabName>
                        <TabValue/>
                        <DocumentID>336845219</DocumentID>
                        <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
                    </TabStatus>
                    <TabStatus>
                        <TabType>DateSigned</TabType>
                        <Status>Signed</Status>
                        <XPosition>195</XPosition>
                        <YPosition>816</YPosition>
                        <TabLabel>Date Signed</TabLabel>
                        <TabName>DateSigned</TabName>
                        <TabValue>11/4/2021 | 7:56 AM PDT</TabValue>
                        <DocumentID>336845219</DocumentID>
                        <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
                    </TabStatus>
                </TabStatuses>
                <RecipientAttachment>
                    <Attachment>
                        <Data>somedaata</Data>
                        <Label>DSXForm</Label>
                    </Attachment>
                </RecipientAttachment>
                <AccountStatus>Closed</AccountStatus>
                <EsignAgreementInformation>
                    <AccountEsignId>GUID</AccountEsignId>
                    <UserEsignId>GUID</UserEsignId>
                    <AgreementDate>2021-11-04T07:55:46.007</AgreementDate>
                </EsignAgreementInformation>
                <FormData>
                    <xfdf>
                        <fields>
                            <field name="DateSigned">
                                <value>11/4/2021 | 7:56 AM PDT</value>
                            </field>
                        </fields>
                    </xfdf>
                </FormData>
                <RecipientId>98525aa9-ae3e-4d1c-aa48-xxxxxxxxxx</RecipientId>
            </RecipientStatus>
        </RecipientStatuses>
        <TimeGenerated>2021-11-04T07:56:23.8331339</TimeGenerated>
        <EnvelopeID>ee738247-57a4-49d7-8914-xxxxxxxx</EnvelopeID>
        <Subject>C345</Subject>
        <UserName>Admin</UserName>
        <Email>Admin@yyy.com</Email>
        <Status>Completed</Status>
        <Created>2021-10-28T11:51:51.707</Created>
        <Sent>2021-11-04T07:44:41.637</Sent>
        <Delivered>2021-11-04T07:55:46.273</Delivered>
        <Signed>2021-11-04T07:56:03.007</Signed>
        <Completed>2021-11-04T07:56:03.007</Completed>
        <ACStatus>Original</ACStatus>
        <ACStatusDate>2021-10-28T11:51:51.707</ACStatusDate>
        <ACHolder>Admin</ACHolder>
        <ACHolderEmail>Admin@yyy.com</ACHolderEmail>
        <ACHolderLocation>DocuSign</ACHolderLocation>
        <SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation>
        <SenderIPAddress>ipaddress   </SenderIPAddress>
        <EnvelopePDFHash/>
        <CustomFields/>
        <AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation>
        <EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping>
        <AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy>
        <DocumentStatuses>
            <DocumentStatus>
                <ID>888888888</ID>
                <Name>C3459</Name>
                <TemplateName/>
                <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            </DocumentStatus>
        </DocumentStatuses>
    </EnvelopeStatus>
    <DocumentPDFs>
        <DocumentPDF>
            <Name>CertificateOfCompletion_GUID.pdf</Name>
            <PDFBytes>Bn8iUlJSRa7MTExKzHx1DNb//bFeKyLoldo39X9/S
            .........
```

and here are the subscribed events

```
Envelope Sent
Envelope Signed/Completed
Envelope Declined
Envelope Voided

Recipient Signed/Completed
Recipient Declined
```

Comment: Which connect events do you sign up for? can you share an example of the payload you get ?

Comment: @InbarGazit - added the sample in original post